# How can I have two strings within an IF(CONTAINS( function?

Tags: formula, formula-field, contains

If the text field contains both "A" and "B", then it should result in "AB".

My formula:

```
if(contains( 
Text_Field__c, "A" & "B" 
), "AB",
```

It goes through; there are no syntax errors. But it doesn´t work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `&&` operator :

```
if((contains(Text_Field__c, "A") && contains(Text_Field__c, "B")), "AB", "")
```

Or use `AND` operator :

```
IF(AND(contains(Text_Field__c, "A"), contains(Text_Field__c, "B")), "AB", "")
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon as this is being used in a formula.